# WiFi too slow compared to cable internet. Ubuntu 14.04 Intel Wireless card

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, internet, dell

First I'd like to say that I have searched a lot and tried many things to solve my problem. But nothing seems to work.

I have a Dell laptop Inspiron-5448 with Ubuntu 14.04. It is new and Ubuntu came pre-installed. My wireless card is Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59).

When I connect the LAN cable from the router to my laptop, the internet works with 30 Mbps. When I'm using WiFi it goes as low as 2Mbps. Sometimes even less.
Other laptops with Windows and even with Ubuntu 14.04 have no problem.

I don't know what to do anymore. I hope there's someone here with enough knowledge to find out what is happening.

Here's the output from [wireless-info](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) script:
**https://paste.ubuntu.com/16642725/**

Comment: Please run the ubuntu forums wireless script (https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) and paste the results into paste.ubuntu.com then edit your answer to include a link to it.

Comment: Done. I hope it is going to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So far we have established that you have a `Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 chip` and you are using the `iwlwifi` driver. The wireless hardware is working at 12Mb/S,  but for some reason `NetworkManager` thinks it is only capable of 1Mb/S.

I have found reports [AC 7265 speed  problem reports](http://AC-7265%20Frequent%20disconnects/Painfully%20slow%20when%20connected) that state that there is a problem with the firmware and that bluetooth and wi-fi both work well as long as they are not switched on at the same time. If you don't need a bluetooth mouse changing to a wired mouse may well be the simplest solution.

Updating to the latest version of the firmware apparently solves this. You can download the latest firmware from  [Intel's Linux driver support page](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi). Make sure you install the firmware for the correct chip and kernel version. You are currently on 3.19.0

You then need to rebuild your kernel to tell it to load the updated firmware file. Instructions for doing so are here. [Loading external firmware tutorial](http://www.crashcourse.ca/wiki/index.php/Loading_external_firmware)

You could also install the driver from a later kernel version or simply try upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS although Wi-Fi problems seem quite common on the current release.

Comment: My current driver firmware version is 25.228.9.0. I've download the latest firmware and copied it to the firmware folder, as the website instructs. But after rebooting the system, the new version is not loaded =(

Comment: Try  a complete rename of the old firmware so it cant possibly be loaded and ensure the new firmware is in the same folder and has the same owner and read write execute permissions.

Comment: Didn't work =( Wifi disappeared after renaming the old files and rebooting.

Comment: I wonder if there's a file where the firmware to be used is determined...

Comment: @gmsalomao2 I looked into it and its hard-wired into the kernel. I have added a link to a tutorial on how to change this, but I have never built a kernel myself.

Comment: OMG! There's gotta be another way. It's too risky.
Do you know if Ubuntu 16.04 comes with updated firmware? How can I look into that?

Comment: Easy. Create a live CD and run 16.04 from that and see if it works.

Comment: this is one of those reasons i get tempted to rage quit linux....it just works in my windows machine, and in my linux machine i'm clocking 2 kHz downloads and need to rebuild the OS kernel to fix it. smh.